# can you attach keys to array variables like a python dictionary?

Tags: php, arrays

Ok so I have this function that eventually returns and array `return array($offset , $currentpage , $totalpages , $rowsperpage);`

I would like to reference this array with keywords like `$variablecontainingarray['offset`] rather than `$variablecontainingarray[0]`

is this possible? I know something similar existed in python. 
`>>> d = {'key':'value'}`

i'd like to have a variable store the output of the array from the function and give a keyword to the values for easier reference.

Comment: Read a manual about arrays please.

Comment: Try this:
`$variablecontainingarray = array();
$variablecontainingarray ['offset'] = $offset;`

Comment: [Your starter for ten](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).... Reading the manual always helps; and there's even a PHP function called [compact()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) that can simplify building an associative array from a series of variables

Comment: When will people _finally_ start reading the documentation of the tools they use?

Comment: @arkascha definitely never(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php you can use arrays in the same way.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php

So you could do:

```
return array(
    'offset'      => $offset,
    'currentpage' => $currentpage,
    'totalpages'  => $totalpages,
    'rowsperpage' => $rowsperpage,
);
```

Furthermore you could use `compact` to keep it all on one line:

```
return compact('offset' , 'currentpage' , 'totalpages' , 'rowsperpage');
```

You can find more information on `compact` here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php

Hope this helps!